# Latest top rated in magento - can't get price

Tags: php, magento, review

Im using a bit of PHP to pull through the top rated products however i can't seem to pull out the Reviews or the Price.

```
<?php

                $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setVisibility(array(2,3,4));

                $_productCollection->joinField('rating_summary', 'review/review_aggregate', 'rating_summary', 'entity_pk_value=entity_id',  array('entity_type' => 1, 'store_id' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()), 'left');                
                $_productCollection->setOrder('rating_summary', 'desc');
                $_productCollection->setPage(1, 5);
            ?>
            <ul id="upsell-product-table">
            <?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>
                <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail'); ?>">

                    <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></h3>

                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true ); ?>


                </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

This is my code, but as you can see:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true ); ?>
```

Doesn't pull out the price, im a bit stuck. Any help would be great.

Comment: In the block or layout, did you add any block for that price html?

Comment: Forgot to mention, it works correctly in a  'recently viewed template' but im entering it into a custom template for a category landing page. I could post the whole on that template i guess... http://pastebin.com/qX43Xtic < its here in this pastebin

Comment: So how did you call this template? <block type="core/template" template="category_landing.phtml" /> ? Please share the details.

Comment: Apologies called it like so on the cat page:

 <reference name="root">
 <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/cat-lander.phtml</template></action>
 </reference>

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code instead of your getPriceHtml($_product, true ); ?>

```
 <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product')->getPriceHtml($_product, true); ?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Seems to break the layout, nothing loads once its added to the phtml file.